# FIFO for images in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

how to use the `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` for the FIFO structure. I want to store the images in that structure.

Is it possible??

Comment: Read the documentation of NSArray / NSMutableArray for example ?

Comment: +1 for Benj. NSMutableArray has the remove... messages necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible:

```
-(void) queueImage:(UIImage*)image {
    [_array addObject:image];
}

-(UIImage*) dequeueImage {
    if (![_array count]) return nil;
    UIImage *image = [[[_array objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];
    [_array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    return image;
}
```

_array must be a NSMutableArray.

Comment: +1 Good point about the stack - clearly too early in the morning for me. (Culled my answer.) :-)